# doThrow() works but thenThrow() doesn't

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to mock a call and I observed one weird thing happening. I am using PowerMockito for mocking.

```
1. when(store.read(Mockito.anyString())).thenThrow(IOException.class);
2. doThrow(IOException.class).when(store).read(Mockito.anyString());
```

When I used statement 1 for mocking the call, I get following error:

```
Runtime Exception (that's all, no stacktrace)
```

When I used statement 2 for mocking the call, it works fine surprisingly.

I have done the mocking of store variable using spring as follows:

```
<bean id="store" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" >
        <constructor-arg value="org.company.state.work.s3.StateGraphStore" />
</bean>
```

I am not sure exactly sure what's the difference between 2 statements and what can be the reason for this to be happening.

Comment: The answer in the dup explains why `doThrow` is safer in some scenarios. Generally speaking in 1. you call `read` directly on your `store` instance, and in 2. you call `read` on a wrapper/proxy created by Mockito. But it's impossible to tell what's happening exactly in your example without knowing what `store` is or what `read` does.

Comment: Sorry, reopened as I accidentally closed this as a dupe without reading the dupe'd question entirely. I'm not confident that this is an exact dupe now.